# Combobox List Width not sizing the dropdown list

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

So I am working in access trying to get different queries to pull specific information when a select case is met.

This is what I have so far

```
Select Case Me.vPipeFlowDirection.Value
    
    Case "All"
        Me.vPipe_Name.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        Me.vPipe_Name.RowSource = "Select * From qryList_V_Profile_PI_AllPipeNames"
        Me.vPipe_Name.ListWidth = 3.5
        Me.vPipe_Name.ColumnCount = 2
        Me.vPipe_Name.ColumnWidths = "3in, 0.5in"
        
    Case Else
        Me.vPipe_Name.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.vPipe_Name.RowSource = "None"
End Select
```

The issue is that the the List Width is working but its putting a horizontal scroll bar instead of making the drop down box bigger

Answer (score 0):

Hy,
The code bellow works.
I assume it is a size in pixels ?
My computer settings are in CM so this might work different with you...

```
  Select Case Me.cboListWidth.Value

    Case "Big Example"
        Me.cboListWidth.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        Me.cboListWidth.RowSource = "Select * from tzzConfig"
        Me.cboListWidth.ListWidth = "8000"
        Me.cboListWidth.ColumnCount = 2
        Me.cboListWidth.ColumnWidths = "2000,4000"
        
    Case Else
        Me.cboListWidth.RowSourceType = "Value List"
        Me.cboListWidth.ListWidth = "2000"
        Me.cboListWidth.RowSource = "None"
    End Select
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did what you are recommending and I copied it over to what you suggested but it still has the scroll bar. I even tried putting the number in "". Tried the value in in, pixel, and cm but nothing breaks it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "just leave the rest" of the 3.5" to the second column:

```
Me!vPipe_Name.ColumnWidths = "3in"
```